# Best Voice track mastering software ?

Tags: pro-tools, software, mastering

Hi all 
Im running Protools HD on Mac and would like some feedback as to what in your opinion is the best voice mastering plug in for feature films.
I have used Ozone 4 and their center voice preset can be slightly harsh at times. Need to add a bit of warmth to the voice track. Location mics were a range of sony lapels and 416 boom. the audio is clean , clinical but no analogue dolby warmth . any suggestions ?

Mark

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick within the izotope family, look at Necter.  It has more features specifically for processing vocals and dialogue, where as ozone is more designed for general mastering.

Comment: Thanks , just downloaded the demo , will give it a try tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

To get back with my own answers , using sonic BBE harmonic exciter as a first stage on the voice tracks followed by down mixing again using Izotope Nectar gives an incredible clarity and warmth to the voice track. Thanks for the heads up on Nectar Auddity